# How to use regular expression on searching

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to use regular expression on searching

EG:

```
<retail:title>Mr</retail:title>

    <retail:title>???</retail:title>
```

I need search that if ??? value count is greater than 2. In above example, it has 'Mr' 2 characters.

Comment: Use an XML parser instead of regex for parsing XML. If you want to match a character X amount of times you can use the `{min, max}` method: `a{4,8}` will match 4 to 8 consequentially `a`'s.

Comment: What is it that you want exactly?

Comment: to search values in notepad ++

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<=>)[^>]{3,}(?=<)`

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).